# Countif is not counting previous years

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie in Excel.  I have a an excel table that looks something like this.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is use countIF to count the date range within January.  My function is something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"N/A",A2:A9,">= "&"Date(2015,1,1)",A2:A9,"<= "&"Date(2015,1,30)")
```

For some reason I'm getting the value 0.

I'm planning on incorporating it into VBA soon but if the function isn't working on excel, most likely it won't work in vba either.  Can please someone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

You should not enclose the `"Date(...)"` with double quotes. This makes Excel take them as litterals, not as a function to generate a date. Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"N/A",A2:A9,">=" & Date(2015,1,1),A2:A9,"<=" & Date(2015,1,30))
```

Also, it might be useful to format your `A` column as `Date`, which I am almost sure you did.